# What happens when memcached key value crosses limit of 1MB?

Tags: caching, memcached

I am using memcached to store reports data in a key. Key size will increase down the road. I have written code to remove old data from the key to keeping the key size as low as possible.

I just want to know, What happens if I am trying to store the key of value greater than 1MB

Answer (score 1):

You will get a "value too large" error or exception, depending a bit on the client you use.

Note that if you run your own memcached instance you can allow it to store larger values with the `-I` flag, i.e.,

```
$ memcached -i 10m
```

for allowing values up to 10MB in size.